# Resolving LPs with constraint addition / deletion in SCIP

Tags: scip

I am trying to implement the following simple LP-based Reoptimization-workflow in SCIP:

```
while (useful)
    SCIPsolve(lpscip)
    for (some_cons)
        SCIPdelCons(lpscip)
    for (some_other_cons)
        SCIPaddCons(lpscip)
```

On this path, I was successful in getting the workflow run without the delCons() part.
For this, I did the following (possibly redundant effects): 
"presolving/maxrounds", 0
"reoptimization/enable", TRUE
SCIPenableReoptimization(lpscip, TRUE);
Call SCIPfreeReoptSolve() after SCIPsolve()

From other posts and the documentation I first felt suggested to use SCIPfreeTransform() instead of SCIPfreeReoptSolve(), but this did not work for me (it gives me the irritating error message
[cons.c:2399] ERROR: constraint handler <benderslp> already initialized
[set.c:5208] ERROR: Error <-8> in function call
when calling SCIPsolve the 2nd time, although not using any benders stuff).

Now, starting from the working addCons flow with SCIPfreeReoptSolve(), when I insert the delCons-part, every call to SCIPdelCons() leads to
[scip_prob.c:2873] ERROR: invalid SCIP stage <7>
and due to the stuff mentioned before, I cannot use freeTransform() before instead.

Could you please indicate to me what is the correct way (series of SCIP methods to call) to implement the mentioned workflow **for LPs and without ConstraintHandlers**?

Maybe it is relevant that I am also not using any own ConstraintHandlers in the above workflow. I am just adding constraints directly via SCIPcreateConsLinear() and SCIPaddCons(), starting from an empty LP.

Side-question: I am using SCIPgetConss() to get the constraint-array after SCIPsolve() and before SCIPReoptSolve(). I will (need to) pass SCIP_CONS * from this array to delCons() after SCIPRepoptSolve(). Am I guaranteed that these stay valid? If not, how could I then get the "right" SCIP_CONS * to pass to SCIPdelCons() without getting "stage problems"?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: please include the versions of scip/pyscipopt that you are using

Comment: Hi Leon, this refers to scip-8 and the C-API (sorry for not mentioning before).

Comment: I came here with the same question, @Informer. Have you had any luck? I'm wondering if, in fact, reoptimization only supports leaving the number of constraints fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had time to look into this before, I'll try to get to it on monday. Do you maybe have a minimal working example with a code that produces the fail?